# How to configure mongodb replicaset of 3 nodes in authentication mode

Tags: replication, mongodb, errors

I had configured a mongodb replicaSet of 3 nodes. It was running fine But WHen i created a adminUser and dbuser on primary node and enabled the authorization in mongodb.conf file of all nodes then they are not connecting. Below is the output of `rs.status()` after enabling authorization. Kindly Help.

```
{
    "set" : "replset1",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-07-15T04:09:41.796Z"),
    "myState" : 3,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.10.8.1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 54841,
            "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1500033801, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-07-14T12:03:21Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.10.8.2:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-07-15T04:09:37.008Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "authenticated" : false,
            "configVersion" : -1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "10.10.8.3:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-07-15T04:09:37.136Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "authenticated" : false,
            "configVersion" : -1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made things in wrong order.
At start you have "open" replica set. You put authorization on and you have so called "localhost exception" what means that you (still) can connect primary directly without authorization. On that connection you MUST first create "root" (super user) user

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
    user: "root",
    pwd: "toor",
    roles: [ "root" ]
})
```

Now, your "localhost exception" is gone! You must authenticate your self. You can logout and then login again OR just give command

`db.auth("root","toor")`

And start creating other (normal) users.